# Calculate post error slowing in R

Tags: r

For my research, I would like to calculate the post-error slowing in the stop signal task to find out whether people become slower after they failed to inhibit their response. Here is some data and I would like to do the following:

1. For each subject determine first if it was a stop-trial (signal = 1)
2. For each stop-trial, determine if it is correct (signal = 1 & correct = 2) and then determine whether the next trial (thus the trial directly after the stop-trial) is a go-trial (signal = 0)

   - Then calculate the average reaction time for all these go-trials that directly follow a stop trial when the response is correct (signal = 0 & correct = 2).
3. For each incorrect stop trial (signal = 1 & correct = 0) determine whether the next trial (thus the trial directly after the stop-trial) is a go-trial (signal = 0)

   - Then calculate the average reaction time for all these go-trials that directly follow a stop-trial when the response is correct (correct = 2).
4. Then calculate the difference between the RTs calculated in step 2 and 3 (= post-error slowing).

I'm not that experienced in R to achieve this. I hope someone can help me with this script.

```
    subject trial   signal  correct RT
    1   1   0   2   755
    1   2   0   2   543
    1   3   1   0   616
    1   4   0   2   804
    1   5   0   2   594
    1   6   0   2   705
    1   7   1   2   0
    1   8   1   2   0
    1   9   0   2   555
    1   10  1   0   604
    1   11  0   2   824
    1   12  0   2   647
    1   13  0   2   625
    1   14  0   2   657
    1   15  1   0   578
    1   16  0   2   810
    1   17  1   2   0
    1   18  0   2   646
    1   19  0   2   574
    1   20  0   2   748
    1   21  0   0   856
    1   22  0   2   679
    1   23  0   2   738
    1   24  0   2   620
    1   25  0   2   715
    1   26  1   2   0
    1   27  0   2   675
    1   28  0   2   560
    1   29  1   0   584
    1   30  0   2   564
    1   31  0   2   994
    1   32  1   2   0
    1   33  0   2   715
    1   34  0   2   644
    1   35  0   2   545
    1   36  0   2   528
    1   37  1   2   0
    1   38  0   2   636
    1   39  0   2   684
    1   40  1   2   0
    1   41  0   2   653
    1   42  0   2   766
    1   43  0   2   747
    1   44  0   2   821
    1   45  0   2   612
    1   46  0   2   624
    1   47  0   2   665
    1   48  1   2   0
    1   49  0   2   594
    1   50  0   2   665
    1   51  1   0   658
    1   52  0   2   800
    1   53  1   2   0
    1   54  1   0   738
    1   55  0   2   831
    1   56  0   2   815
    1   57  0   2   776
    1   58  0   2   710
    1   59  0   2   842
    1   60  1   0   516
    1   61  0   2   758
    1   62  1   2   0
    1   63  0   2   628
    1   64  0   2   713
    1   65  0   2   835
    1   66  1   0   791
    1   67  0   2   871
    1   68  0   2   816
    1   69  0   2   769
    1   70  0   2   930
    1   71  0   2   676
    1   72  0   2   868
    2   1   0   2   697
    2   2   0   2   689
    2   3   0   2   584
    2   4   1   0   788
    2   5   0   2   448
    2   6   0   2   564
    2   7   0   2   587
    2   8   1   0   553
    2   9   0   2   706
    2   10  0   2   442
    2   11  1   0   245
    2   12  0   2   601
    2   13  0   2   774
    2   14  1   0   579
    2   15  0   2   652
    2   16  0   2   556
    2   17  0   2   963
    2   18  0   2   725
    2   19  0   2   751
    2   20  0   2   709
    2   21  0   2   741
    2   22  1   0   613
    2   23  0   2   781
    2   24  1   2   0
    2   25  0   2   634
    2   26  1   2   0
    2   27  0   2   487
    2   28  1   2   0
    2   29  0   2   692
    2   30  0   2   745
    2   31  1   2   0
    2   32  0   2   610
    2   33  0   2   836
    2   34  1   0   710
    2   35  0   2   757
    2   36  0   2   781
    2   37  0   2   1029
    2   38  0   2   832
    2   39  1   0   626
    2   40  1   2   0
    2   41  0   2   844
    2   42  0   2   837
    2   43  0   2   792
    2   44  0   2   789
    2   45  0   2   783
    2   46  0   0   0
    2   47  0   0   468
    2   48  0   2   686
```

Comment: I see you work with row-related conditions here. So a first and easy step would be to use logical vectors (TRUE/FALSE) for each condition: `data[,"condition1"] <- data[,"signal"] == 1; 

data[,"condition2"] <- data[,"condition1"] & data[,"correct"] == 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be too late to be useful but here's my solution: (i.e. I first split the data frame by subject, and then apply the same algorithm to each subject; the result is:

```
  #          1         2 
  #  -74.60317  23.39286 


X <- read.table(
text="      subject trial signal  correct RT
                  1   1   0   2   755
                  1   2   0   2   543
                  1   3   1   0   616
                  1   4   0   2   804
                  1   5   0   2   594
                  1   6   0   2   705
                  1   7   1   2   0
                  1   8   1   2   0
                  1   9   0   2   555
                  1   10  1   0   604
                  1   11  0   2   824
                  1   12  0   2   647
                  1   13  0   2   625
                  1   14  0   2   657
                  1   15  1   0   578
                  1   16  0   2   810
                  1   17  1   2   0
                  1   18  0   2   646
                  1   19  0   2   574
                  1   20  0   2   748
                  1   21  0   0   856
                  1   22  0   2   679
                  1   23  0   2   738
                  1   24  0   2   620
                  1   25  0   2   715
                  1   26  1   2   0
                  1   27  0   2   675
                  1   28  0   2   560
                  1   29  1   0   584
                  1   30  0   2   564
                  1   31  0   2   994
                  1   32  1   2   0
                  1   33  0   2   715
                  1   34  0   2   644
                  1   35  0   2   545
                  1   36  0   2   528
                  1   37  1   2   0
                  1   38  0   2   636
                  1   39  0   2   684
                  1   40  1   2   0
                  1   41  0   2   653
                  1   42  0   2   766
                  1   43  0   2   747
                  1   44  0   2   821
                  1   45  0   2   612
                  1   46  0   2   624
                  1   47  0   2   665
                  1   48  1   2   0
                  1   49  0   2   594
                  1   50  0   2   665
                  1   51  1   0   658
                  1   52  0   2   800
                  1   53  1   2   0
                  1   54  1   0   738
                  1   55  0   2   831
                  1   56  0   2   815
                  1   57  0   2   776
                  1   58  0   2   710
                  1   59  0   2   842
                  1   60  1   0   516
                  1   61  0   2   758
                  1   62  1   2   0
                  1   63  0   2   628
                  1   64  0   2   713
                  1   65  0   2   835
                  1   66  1   0   791
                  1   67  0   2   871
                  1   68  0   2   816
                  1   69  0   2   769
                  1   70  0   2   930
                  1   71  0   2   676
                  1   72  0   2   868
                  2   1   0   2   697
                  2   2   0   2   689
                  2   3   0   2   584
                  2   4   1   0   788
                  2   5   0   2   448
                  2   6   0   2   564
                  2   7   0   2   587
                  2   8   1   0   553
                  2   9   0   2   706
                  2   10  0   2   442
                  2   11  1   0   245
                  2   12  0   2   601
                  2   13  0   2   774
                  2   14  1   0   579
                  2   15  0   2   652
                  2   16  0   2   556
                  2   17  0   2   963
                  2   18  0   2   725
                  2   19  0   2   751
                  2   20  0   2   709
                  2   21  0   2   741
                  2   22  1   0   613
                  2   23  0   2   781
                  2   24  1   2   0
                  2   25  0   2   634
                  2   26  1   2   0
                  2   27  0   2   487
                  2   28  1   2   0
                  2   29  0   2   692
                  2   30  0   2   745
                  2   31  1   2   0
                  2   32  0   2   610
                  2   33  0   2   836
                  2   34  1   0   710
                  2   35  0   2   757
                  2   36  0   2   781
                  2   37  0   2   1029
                  2   38  0   2   832
                  2   39  1   0   626
                  2   40  1   2   0
                  2   41  0   2   844
                  2   42  0   2   837
                  2   43  0   2   792
                  2   44  0   2   789
                  2   45  0   2   783
                  2   46  0   0   0
                  2   47  0   0   468
                  2   48  0   2   686", header=TRUE)

sapply(split(X, X["subject"]), function(D){
  PCRT <- with(D, RT[which(c(signal[-1],NA)==1 & c(correct[-1], NA)==2 & signal==0) ])
  PERT <- with(D, RT[which(c(signal[-1],NA)==1 & c(correct[-1], NA)==0 & signal==0) ])
  mean(PERT) - mean(PCRT)
})
```

This is ok if you can be sure that every respondent has at least 1 correct and 1 incorrect "stop" trial followed by a "go" trial. A more general case would be (giving NA if they are either always correct or always mistaken):

```
sapply(split(X, X["subject"]), function(D){
  PCRT <- with(D, RT[which(c(signal[-1],NA)==1 & c(correct[-1], NA)==2 & signal==0) ])
  PERT <- with(D, RT[which(c(signal[-1],NA)==1 & c(correct[-1], NA)==0 & signal==0) ])
  if(length(PCRT)>0 & length(PERT)>0) mean(PERT) - mean(PCRT) else NA
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Does that help you? A little bit redundant maybe, but I tried to follow your steps as best as possible (not sure whether I mixed something up, please check for yourself looking at the table). The idea is to put the data in a csv file first and treat it as a data frame. Find the csv raw file here: http://pastebin.com/X5b2ysmQ

```
data <- read.csv("datatable.csv",header=T)

data[,"condition1"] <- data[,"signal"] == 1
data[,"condition2"] <- data[,"condition1"] & data[,"correct"] == 2

data[,"RT1"] <- NA
for(i in which(data[,"condition2"])){
  if( nrow(data)>i && !data[i+1,"condition1"] && data[i+1,"correct"] == 2  )
    # next is a go trial
    data[i+1,"RT1"] <- data[i+1,"RT"]
}
averageRT1 <- mean( data[ !is.na(data[,"RT1"]) ,"RT1"] )

data[,"RT2"] <- NA
for(i in which(data[,"condition1"] & data[,"correct"] == 0)){
  if( nrow(data)>i && !data[i+1,"condition1"] && data[i+1,"correct"] == 2  )
    # next is a go trial
    data[i+1,"RT2"] <- data[i+1,"RT"]
}
averageRT2 <- mean( data[ !is.na(data[,"RT2"]) ,"RT2"] )

postErrorSlowing <- abs(averageRT2-averageRT1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @nilsole, I will try it later today!

Answer (score 0):

@Nilsole I just tried it and it is almost perfect. How could the code be improved that for each subject the postErrorSlowing is calculated and placed in a dataframe? Thus that a new data frame is created which consists of subject number (1,2,3 etc.) and the postErrorSlowing variable? Something like this (postErrorSlowing are made up numbers)

```
subject postErrorSlowing
1           50
2           75
```

....

Comment: What is the exact definition of the postErrorSlowing? The absolute difference between one RT value and the RT value in the row before?

Comment: postErrorSlowing is that people become slower after they made a mistake. Here it is defined as the average RT of the go trials after an incorrect stop trial ("RT2") minus the average RT of the go trials after a correct stop trial ("RT1"). The higher this value, the slower one is after he or she made a mistake. This is what you have exactly calculated (I removed the abs in the code). But I would like to calculate this value for every subject. So it somehow has to be placed in a for loop I guess and this value has to be written to a data frame. So every subject has one value for postErrorSlowing

Comment: ok I will have another look. but nevertheless, I guess this all is pretty easy to do with vectors.

Comment: You would like to do a calculation for every subject. So, my question is: How many subjects are there? 2? Or are there 120? Do you expect two values or 120?

Comment: I think I fixed it:
   data2 <- ddply(data,~subject,summarise, meanStopCor=mean(RT1,na.rm = TRUE), meanStopInc=mean(RT2,na.rm = TRUE))
    data2$PES <- (data2$meanStopInc - data2$meanStopCor)